# Remove blank "---------" from RadioSelect

Tags: python, django

I don't find a way to remove the first line from my `Choices_list` which is displayed like `-------`.

I already tried some things : `blank=True`, `Blank=False`, ... and this line is still there.

This is what I'm getting in my Django website :

[image]

My `models.py` and `forms.py` files look like :

```
# models.py
# coding: utf-8

from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

FAVORITE_THEME = (
    ('Datasystems', 'Datasystems'),
    ('Cameroun', 'Cameroun'),
)

class Theme(models.Model):
    favorite_theme = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=FAVORITE_THEME, verbose_name="Sélectionner le thème")



# forms.py
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Theme

class ThemeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Theme
        widgets = {'favorite_theme' : forms.RadioSelect,}
        fields=('favorite_theme',)
```

Do you have an idea to delete or hide this line ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try removing the comma after ('Cameroun', 'Cameroun')?

Comment: @MKesper It's not the problem ^^

Comment: Add `blank=False` for `favorite_theme` in `Theme` model. It should work.

Comment: @gitblame I had already tried to add `blank=False` because by default, `blank=True` but the line is still there :/ `favorite_theme = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=FAVORITE_THEME, verbose_name="Sélectionner le thème", blank=False)`.

Comment: @Andro Try adding a default along with `blank=False`.

Comment: Thank you ! Seems to work fine ! I wrote : `favorite_theme = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=FAVORITE_THEME, verbose_name="Sélectionner le thème", default=None, blank=False)`. Add this line as the answer and I will validate it ;)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I've added an answer with relevant documentation. Do accept the answer for sake of future users.

Answer (score 6):

From [Django ModelForm docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types):

> If the model field has **choices** set, then the form field’s **widget** will be set to **Select**, with choices coming from the model field’s **choices**. The choices will normally include the blank choice which is selected by default. If the field is required, this forces the user to make a selection. The blank choice will not be included if the model field has **blank=False** and an explicit **default** value (the **default** value will be initially selected instead).

So to exclude blank choice in the form, both `blank=False` and `default` must be provided. Only setting `blank=False` will not work.

Comment: Thanks, as I said in my question' answers I found the solution with ``default=none` and `blank=False` ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but in case other users find this through Google: you need to add `, blank=False, default='Unspecified'` to your field.

Like this:

```
favorite_theme = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=FAVORITE_THEME, verbose_name="Sélectionner le thème", blank=False, default='Unspecified')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like below.

```
import copy
from django import forms
from .models import Theme

class InhSelect(forms.widgets.Select):
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        self.choices = self.choices[1:]
        obj = copy.copy(self)
        obj.attrs = self.attrs.copy()
        obj.choices = copy.copy(self.choices)
        memo[id(self)] = obj
        return obj

class MyRadioSelect(forms.widgets.RendererMixin, InhSelect):
    renderer = forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer
    _empty_value = ''

class ThemeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Theme
        widgets = {'favorite_theme' : MyRadioSelect(),}
        fields=('favorite_theme',)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if you didn't see in my question' comments, I got the solution ^^ Just adding `default=None` ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might be some out of way, but if someone else get stuck on this issue.

You can put one of the two choices as default.
like this,

```
class Theme(models.Model):
    favorite_theme = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=FAVORITE_THEME, default="Datasystems",verbose_name="Sélectionner le thème")
```

This must work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way. You can just manipulate the choices like this:

class Cotizacion_Review(forms.ModelForm):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Cotizacion_Review, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['nota'].widget.choices[0] = ('','-')
```

In this case I wanted to change the default "--------" by just a "-" .  But you could have edited the whole list of choices for example.